# erros using export default in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyyJO.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7KBY.png)

I was trying to run the above code but I can't and in the browser I can't see anything.
Is there another way to write code in `<scripts setup> </script>`? I learned that the functions go into
`export default { name: 'App', //code }`
Because when I type anything else, like `console.log('It runs')`, I get an error and I can't even see the 'hello world'? Please, help ;-;

Comment: You shouldn't be exporting at all if you're using `<script setup>`.

Answer (score 0):

your code error

```
// App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted,reactive, toRefs } from 'vue'

const state = reactive({
    showNavbar: 'xxxx'
})
const { showNavbar } = toRefs(state)

onMounted(async() => {
   console.log('hello world')
})

</script>

<template>

    <main>
         <RouterView />
    </main>
   
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```